# Replace nth Substring With nth Strings of Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, format

I have a string like so:

```
"initWithType:bundleIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier:"
```

and two lists like so:

```
['long long', 'id', 'id']
['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

and want to end up with the string:

```
"initWithType:(long long)arg1 bundleIdentifier:(id)arg2 uniqueIdentifier:(id)arg3"
```

As you may see, I effectively need to replace every nth semicolon with the nth string in each list (plus a little formatting with parentheses and a space).

I have been trying to use `.format` and the `*` unpacking operator but have had little success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of string formatting with `zip`:

```
s1 = "initWithType:bundleIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier:"
l2 = ['long long', 'id', 'id']
l3 = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']

print(" ".join("{}:({}){}".format(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(s1.split(":"), l2, l3)))
```

Edit: you can also use f-strings with Python >= 3.6 as suggested by @flakes:

```
print(" ".join(f"{a}:({b}){c}" for a, b, c in zip(s1.split(":"), l2, l3)))
```

this will print

```
initWithType:(long long)arg1 bundleIdentifier:(id)arg2 uniqueIdentifier:(id)arg3
```

Comment: Just as a another point on this option; for people not using python >= 3.6, you really should upgrade. 3.5 hits end-of-life very soon!! https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches